# Hpw tp Create SQLite3 .db file with Python

Tags: python, database, windows, sqlite, creation

The below code works as-is, but changing the raw string (last statement) to a variable does not.

Why? How do I make it work with a variable?

```py
def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to a SQLite database """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_connection(r"C:\sqlite\db\pythonsqlite.db")
```

Comment: _How do I make it work with a variable?_ You must have made some mistake.  Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You simply define `path` and pass it into `create_connection` as usual:

```py
import sqlite3

def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to a SQLite database """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.close()

path = r"C:\sqlite\db\pythonsqlite.db"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_connection(path)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am puzzzled because I tried that very thing but Sublime complained about the \ and  \\ and  or / did nit work.  Perhaps something to do with Sublime?

Comment: @farkled I use vs code but noticed a similar issue, it's just a matter of syntax highlighting. Apparently the python extension doesn't pick up the raw string modifier and treats the string literal as normal thus complains about unescaped backslashes ( \\ )